# Verificando string dentro de string

Tags: java, string

Como saber se uma texto em específico está contido em uma *string*?

exemplo:

```
String str = " Hello Word";
```

Como eu faço para verificar se a palavra "Hello" está contida naquela *string* "str".

E se a verificação for verdadeira, como edita-lá.

Caso haja a palavra "Hello" na *string* "str" então a palavra "Hello" será mudada para "Olá"

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 11):

Para verificar use o método [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) e para trocar use o [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-).

```
String str = " Hello Word";
if (str.contains("Hello")) {
    str = str.replace("Hello", "Olá"); //note que é necessário reatribuir a variável
}
```

Ou otimizado:

```
String str = " Hello Word";
str = str.replace("Hello", "Olá");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/otZQmF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dhtxaihz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/ReplaceIfExists.java).

Afinal, se não tem, não fará a troca. Eu fiz a primeira para atender o que você pediu, talvez queira conhecer o `contains()`.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu queria :)

Comment: @HigorBarbosa melhor que obrigado, o mais correto é você aceitar a resposta e votar nela (você pode votar em tudo no site). Veja o [tour] para entender melhor.